# WCF Wrong URL using Clustered Machine

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-6

I have a WCF (NET 3.5) service published on a clustered machine which has IIS 6.0 configured with two websites:

- The First responds to any unassigned IP
- The second one responds to a specific IP

The problem I am facing is that when I access the service via Http I am getting the WCF web page with the tutorial with the wrong URL (it uses the machine name of a machine which responds to the IP mapped to the first site instead of the one responding to the second address) resulting in all my clients failing to contact the service.

How can I fix this behaviour? Bear in mind that I cannot change the IPs assisgned to the sites and I cannot use:

```
<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
```

since i am on .NEt 3.5